# How to protect the /metrics, /health and /openapi endpoints in Quarkus?

Tags: security, configuration, quarkus, microprofile

Quarkus use the `/metrics` endpoint to provide metrics data, the `/health` endpoint to provide the application status (`UP` or `DOWN`) and the `/openapi` endpoint to provide information about the available endpoints. This endpoints are defined by the Eclipse Microprofile Specifications.

By default this endpoints are public. I want protect this endpoints to only authenticated and authorized users can access.

How to protect this endpoints using Quarkus?

I want that the applications returns `403` for unauthorized users.

To authenticate I want use a basic authentication or a JWT token.

Is possible create a filter to this endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This configuration should help:

```
quarkus.http.auth.permission.public.paths=/health/*,/metrics/*,/openapi/*
quarkus.http.auth.permission.public.policy=authenticated
```

You can start from the basic authentication as recommended [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/security#authenticating-via-http).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus 3.x has an option to have management endpoints on a separate port:

```
quarkus.management.enabled=true
quarkus.management.port=9000
```